# Android's new Google Play Game Services leaderboard API

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, leaderboard

With the release of Android's new `Google Play Game Services` the other day, I wanted to implement the leaderboard they had.  After reading [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards), am I reading it correctly that it is not possible to let the user submit multiples *scores* to *one* leaderboard?  It seems so from reading but that is disappointing if that is true.  I am hoping I am just reading it incorrectly or there is another link somewhere that lets me implement what I need!

My question is if there is a way to use Android's new `Game Services` leaderobard where the user can submit multiples scores to 1 leaderboard and not just have the leaderboard store the highest score the user has gotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point submitting multiple scores to a leaderboard.

This is what the [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards)

> The game services checks if this score is better than the player's
>   current leaderboard entry for the daily, weekly, or all-time score. If
>   it is, the game services updates the corresponding leaderboards with
>   the new score.

Why do you want to submit multiple scores to one leaderboard ?

If you have different levels you can [create different leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#creating_a_leaderboard) for that.

> Games can have multiple leaderboards, up to a maximum of 100. For
>   example, a multi-level game might provide a different leaderboard for
>   each level, and a racing game might have a separate leaderboard for
>   each track.

Solution for your Comment

> The game services sends a score report back to the game client. This
>   report tells the client whether this is a new daily, weekly, or
>   all-time high score. If it isn't, the game services will tell the
>   client what the current daily, weekly, or all-time high score is for
>   this player.

Comment: The thing is right now I have SwarmConnect's leaderboard and I am not 100% pleased with it but they do allow me to have users submit as many times to a leaderboard as they want.  I feel like I would now upset my users if I switch it so they can only submit one score to each leaderboard.

Comment: 1. Users are not submitting the scroe on their own with this Google Api. Read my Answer and you'll know that.